# how to setup java runtime environment on windows 10

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, windows-10

I got windows 10 some days ago but when I tried to run an application (.exe), it gave 
[the following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6iQn.jpg)

> the registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment instalation or the runtime is corrupted.
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

Does anyone knows how to fix this, I assume that I have to change something in the environment variables, but I cannot find good information about it for windows 10.

Comment: maybe this leads you the way: http://superuser.com/questions/269343/java-issue-nonexistent-java-runtime - however related answers are Windows 7 specific. Nevertheless, try to check it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you have some entries in your registry which point at invalid paths.

- Check the enabled Java Runtime versions from the **Java Control Panel**(`java` tab under the **Java Control Panel**).
- Delete the other **jre**(not **jdk**) version's from the Java installation directory (mostly `C:\Program Files\Java`).
- Open the registry editor ( <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type in
  **regedit** ).
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.x`(here *x* is the jre version).
- Verify the paths(**values**) of the **JavaHome** key under each folder of `1.x` whether they are actually present under the given directory.

You'll find some invalid entries there, just delete those entries (corresponding folder under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\`) and reinstall your **exe** application.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling, you can also:
1. Create or modify String value `CurrentVersion` in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` key to match your Java version (`1.x`).
2. Create or modify String value `JavaHome` in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.x` key to point at your installed JRE directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.xxx`).

This seems to be the path through which applications get the jre directory, if they are not getting it through the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently when trying to run freemind. the way i solved it in win10 was this:

Using OO RegEdit I searched for `java runtime environment` and found it under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

rather than all the places that other articles mention for win7 ....etc.

I removed the invalid entries for jre7 and the app started working immediately. HTH